# SQL - Loading data from CSV file & using that data to find instances in another table

Tags: sql, csv, psql

I am new to SQL and I was wondering if there was any way to search a table for instances with values from a column of an external table (csv file). To explain that in a clearer manner, this is what I'm working on: If a column in the csv file contains latitudes and another column contained longitudes; I want to search a table that contains information about several locations, with their Latitudes and Longitudes specified in the table.

I want to retrieve the information about that particular location with Latitudes and Longitudes as input from  a csv file.

Would it look something like this? :

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable(  
  latitude DECIMAL(5, 2) NOT NULL, 
  longitude DECIMAL(5, 2) NOT NULL
);

LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Catalog.csv'
INTO TABLE MyTable
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'

SELECT
  main.object_id, 
  main.latitude, 
  main.longitude, 
  main.Some_Information

FROM
  location_info AS main,
  MyTable AS temp

WHERE
  main.latitude = temp.latitude AND
  main.longitude = temp.longitude
```

I also tried using psql's \copy like:

```
\copy MyTable FROM 'C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Catalog.csv' WITH CSV;
```

As given here -> http://postgresguide.com/utilities/copy.html. 
But this didn't work either. There was an error near "\" at or near copy, but then this could be because of the presence of an older version of psql.
Also I am not a Superuser, hence the use of \copy and not COPY FROM.

I also tried using a temporary table and using \copy alongside it. It gave the same error as above.

Comment: Welcome to SO, CrunchyMint. You've tagged multiple different databases in your question. If you're using PostgreSQL as your post implies, please remove your `mysql` and `sql-server` tags as those are totally different RDMSs.

Comment: What is the exact error you're getting?

Comment: Sorry about that, I edited them.

Comment: ^ syntax error at or near "DATA" ---> This was what I got for the above code

Comment: and ^ syntax error at or near "\" ---> was what I got for the \copy

Comment: Looks like your issue revolves around not naming your columns, and your use of `\`. Give my answer a whirl :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PostgreSQL does not support the `LOAD DATA` syntax you're using. You'll need to use `COPY` instead.

Your workflow should look more like:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable(  
  latitude DECIMAL(5, 2) NOT NULL, 
  longitude DECIMAL(5, 2) NOT NULL
);

COPY MyTable(latitude, longitude) 
FROM 'C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Catalog.csv' WITH CSV;

SELECT
  main.object_id, 
  main.latitude, 
  main.longitude, 
  main.Some_Information
FROM
  location_info AS main
  JOIN MyTable AS temp
    on main.latitude = temp.latitude 
    and main.longitude = temp.longitude
```

There are three main things to notice here.

1. I've removed your `\` from the `COPY` command.
2. I've specified the columns that you're trying to insert into with the `COPY` command. If the columns are in a different order in the CSV file, simply reorder them in the `COPY` expression.
3. I've changed the syntax of your join to a standard ANSI join. The logic is the same, but this is a better standard to use for readability/compatibility reasons.